# Extract SplineSet/other information from Truetype font

Tags: c++, fonts, truetype, spline

How can I extract the SplineSet and other information from a TTF? I need to do this in C++. Any links/reads will be helpful, too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some information about the file format [here](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=IWS-Chapter08) [here](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/ttrefman/rm06/Chap6.html) and [here](http://www.truetype-typography.com/ttspec.htm). Hope it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

When you say splineset, do you mean the vector outlines of the glyphs in the TTF?

You can extract the vector outlines and other font data using [freetype](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step1.html) (a C library).

updated:
I am not sure what you want to do with the font, but be aware that the font specs is a little....heavy.

Comment: Hi gilamesh, we're looking for a font expert for our startup (en.youscribe.com). Are you interested in doing some work for us ? If so, feel free to contact me : yann.robin (at) youscribe [.com]